# Integer count: For i = 0

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

As I am a beginner to programming and trying extremely hard to grasp some of the key concepts which are not Always that clear to me, I would like to ask a theory type question. The code below is a simple code in the MS Access 2010 (by Groh) user guide  which upon clicking a button (cmdWith) transforms the font and its colour of both a button (control) and a text box (control).   For the most part, i understand the logic of the code but I cant get my head around the integer part..  In particularly I don't understand the line:

```
For i = 0 To Me.Controls.Count -1
```

the -1 for me is extremely strange..  Is the code counting backwards??  Below is the full sub routine..  Thank you very much.

```
Private Sub cmdWith_Click()
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim c As Control

  For i = 0 To Me.Controls.Count - 1
    Set c = Me(i)
    If TypeOf c Is CommandButton Then
      With c
        .FontName = "Arial"
        .FontBold = True
        .FontSize = 8
      End With
    ElseIf TypeOf c Is TextBox Then
      With c
        .FontName = "MS Sans Serif"
        .FontBold = False
        .FontSize = 8
        .ForeColor = 0 'Black
      End With
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Also look at the Access help topic for the *"For Each...Next Statement"*.  You wouldn't need to build the `For` control statement based on the variable, `i`, just ... `For Each c In Me.Controls`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is counting forwards. The -1 just subtracts 1 from `Me.Controls.Count` -- think of the grouping as `For (i) = (0) To (Me.Controls.Count -1)`. Notice that the counting starts from 0, not 1, so you need that `- 1` to have the correct number of passes through this `For` loop. Said another way, the sequence counting from 1 to Me.Controls.Count has the same number of elements as the sequence counting from 0 to (Me.Controls.Count-1)

You'll find that many, but not all, languages start counting from 0 instead of 1 for array indexing like this; the 0 index means "offset 0 positions from the start of the array". This makes a lot of math on arrays much simpler (IMO), at the light expense of having to remember to count from 0 to n-1 instead of from 1 to n.

Answer (score 2):

```
For i = 0 To Me.Controls.Count - 1
```

Note the space in the original. It's not "negative one", it's subtracting 1 from the number `Me.Controls.Count`. The loop starts at 0 and ends at 1 less than `Me.Controls.Count`. So if `Me.Controls.Count` were 5, the loop would go from 0 to 4.

Comment: In Italian we say "sei un grande" (you are fantastic)..  Thank you very much.. As you can see, I am lacking certain conceptual basics.   One last question, out of curiosity, what happens if instead of doing Me.Controls.Count -1 I just put a number in..  For example 5...   If there are 10 controls on the form, what would happen??

Comment: @MarcheseIlChihuahua Good question. What do you think would happen? Why don't you try to guess, then try it and see if you were right? Making a prediction then testing your prediction is a great way to learn!

Comment: My guess is that it would only change 5 out of the controls. Which ones however,  I would not know.